# JSON string extract in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a class `Test` and it has 2 string variables.

```
Class Test {
    String id;
    String priority;

     Getters();
     Setters();
}
```

I have converted my class to JSON 'return Response.ok(test).build();  here test is object of class `Test`

Here, I am getting a list of test objects as:

```
[{"id":"INC0000001","priority":"High"},{"id":"INC0000001","priority":"Low"}
```

I need to extract the data in jQuery now. I am trying this:

```
$.each(json, function () {
   $.each(this, function (name, value) {
      console.log(name + '=' + value);
   });
});
```

I need to print the values back to HTML and need to get those values from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check i have added, and its working

```js
var json = [{"id":"INC0000001","priority":"HIGH"},{"id":"INC0000001","priority":"HIGH"},{"id":"INC0000002","priority":"CRITICAL"}];
    var countPriority_ecomm_high = 0;
    var countPriority_ecomm_low = 0;
    var countPriority_ecomm_medium = 0;
    var countPriority_ecomm_critical = 0;
$.each(json, function( key, value ) {       
    if (value.priority == "HIGH"){
        countPriority_ecomm_high++;
    }

    if (value.priority == "MEDIUM"){
        countPriority_ecomm_medium++;
    }

    if (value.priority == "LOW"){
        countPriority_ecomm_low++;
    }

    if (value.priority == "CRITICAL"){
        countPriority_ecomm_critical++;
    }
     
    })
 alert('HIGH ='+ countPriority_ecomm_high +', LOW ='+ countPriority_ecomm_low+', MEDIUM ='+countPriority_ecomm_medium+', CRITICAL ='+ countPriority_ecomm_critical)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton pal, your code made my day, I learned a lot and thanks to all whoever helped me. happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

What exact HTML do you want to get? Here is an example of parsing JSON and formatting output HTML:

```js
var json = [{"id":"INC0000001","priority":"High"},{"id":"INC0000001","priority":"Low"}];

var ul = $("<ul/>");

$.each(json, function () {
    var li = $("<li/>").text(this.id + ' has ' + this.priority + " priority");
    ul.append(li);  
});

$("body").append(ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it worked well. Now, if the list size increased and we want a grouping of 'priority' values. Say for example - the list size is 50, and in the JSON we got 30 'Low' & 20 'High', how to do the looping with $.each and print that in html : High : 20    Low: 30, I am sorry as i am very new to this.

Comment: It's another story and it has many solutions. You can use 'for' loop or jQuery's 'each' function to go through your array and calculate what you want, or use 'reduce' function, for example.

Comment: Some examples: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/journeyman/vo9ap116/). The shortest solution is with 'filter' function. But your environment must support ECMAScript 5

Comment: Thanks. Pretty helpful with different examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$.each(json, function (index, value) {
    console.log('id =' + value.id +', priority ='+ value.priority );
});
```

Comment: Hi, the values are coming. Now I want to add a counter to it.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you **counter** ?

Comment: Hi, your code is doing perfectly fine, Now i tried to add a counter with above piece of code to get the total count of priority and it seems the values are coming as 'undefined'

Comment: @saptarsiMondal check i have posted new answer